# Export a whole MS Access database to CSV

Tags: ms-access, csv

I have a 37 table MS Access database.  I have, in the past, exported the tables to CSV one at a time.  Is there a way to export the tables to CSV in a single stroke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [TableDefs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984808%28VS.71%29.aspx) collection and [TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141567%28office.10%29.aspx).